# Need Images to maximize on mouseover in HTML pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I m have  thumbnail  images in  a table and on mouseover the image i should get as blow up and on  mouseout it should be normal thumbnail.  and i even need to navigate on clicking the Blowup image.
plz guide me with the code of how to do it using javascript or using CSS

I need some thing as in this website : [link text](http://tstongshun.en.alibaba.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the jQuery Plugins, you could probably configure the [ThickBox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Or a pure CSS implementation, doesn't work on IE6 though.
[CSS Light Box](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/lightbox-hover.html)

Answer (score 0):

question:  do you have two pics? One for thumbnail one for enlarged pic?   or only one image that changing size?
do u want it gradually maximize or instantly become large?

For 1st case, just do:

```
function mouseOverFun() {
document.getElementById('imageName').src = "largeImage.jpg";
}  // just do the reverse for mouseOut event.
```

for 2nd case, if it enlarge gradually, look at jQuery.
if not, just change the element size.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery, or any other Javascript library has a host of things you could use to make a fancy gallery.

Try this site:

http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html

Take a look at the demos pages; excellent ideas for what you're looking for.